# WPF Validate custom objects in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I am using Mvvm Community Toolkit's [ObservableValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observablevalidator) for validating viewmodel properties. When there is some custom object in my view model that is bind to the view, how to validate all of these properties, without having to move all of model properties to view model.

I don't really want to decorate my domain models with bunch of validating attributes, but I want to decorate my object inside viewmodel with some validating attribute.

```cs
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class MyViewModel : ObservableValidator
{
    private Product _product;
    
    [CustomValidation(typeof(MyViewModel), nameof(ValidateProduct))]      
    public Product Product 
    { 
      get => _product; 
      set => SetProperty(ref _product, value, false); 
    }
      
    public static ValidationResult ValidateProduct(string name, ValidationContext context)
    {
      //Do validation on all Product properties

      if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Product.Name))
      {
        //Add validation result
      }  
    }
}
```

How to validate all object properties and add it to some ValidationErrors list ? It doesn't have to be done using Mvvm Community Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

When you look into the implementation of `ObservableValidator.SetProperty` you'll find that validation is triggered only when the property is changed. This would mean that you have to set the whole `Product` to trigger your validation. I assume, you have input fields bound to `Product.Name` (and further properties), which won't issue a recreation of the `Product` property.

I agree with your intention not to decorate domain models with ui related stuff. But IMO the correct way to prevent that, is not to use domain models in the ui. So, if `Product` is a domain model, remove it from `MyViewModel`. Instead either create a full `ProductViewModel` (which still might be a property of `MyViewModel`, but you would need to set a *local* `DataContext` to not mess up binding paths) or add the needed properties to your `MyViewModel`. Then you can do input validation in the viewmodel. This might also allow you to use standard validation rules and not having to implement a custom validation.

As domain validation can include complex logic involving related domain models, current state etc. which are not available in the ui, I'd go with basic validation (input required, dates/numbers within a range etc.) and do a full validation when data is given back to the domain part.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I tryed to create DTO based on Domain model and put my validation attributes there, but with no success. Also, I am calling ValidateAllProperties method ( avaliable in MvvM toolkit) when command is executing, but it is not validating properties on my DTO ( which is property on MyViewModel). I didn't fully understand this part "but you would need to set a local DataContext to not mess up binding paths", DataContext of a View is set to MyViewModel.

Comment: @salttoinjury Regarding "it's not validating": Why did you create a `ProductDto` instead of a `ProductViewModel`. Does the Dto inherit from `ObservableValidator`?

Comment: @salttoinjury regarding DataContext: `SetProperty` fires the `PropertyChanged` event with a property name of `Name` (referencing the "Name" property on the `ProductViewModel`). If you have your `MyViewModel` set as `DataContext` the correct path to the property would be `Product.Name` ... so, these don't match. To fix that, you need to e.g. create a container for your product inputs and set its `DataContext` to the `Product` property.